# Getting the largest number from each of the 2 arrays

Tags: java

In my self study of Java, I'm trying to get the largest number from each of the 2 arrays

I don't know why the following output is being executed:

```
Largest: 3
Largest: 8
Largest: 9
Largest: 23
Largest: 33
Largest: 41
Largest: 51
```

The correct output should be:

```
Largest: 23
Largest: 51
```

How could the following code get the largest number? Because `(getLargest1[i] > largest)`

is equal to `getLargest1[i] > 0`, which `largest = 0`.

And why should `largest = getLargest1[i];`?

---

```
public class MyProgram
{
    public void start()
    {
        int[] getLargest1 = {3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 5, 23, 14};
        int[] getLargest2 = {33, 23, 41, 9, 17, 51, 23, 45};
        getLargestFunc(getLargest1, getLargest2);
    }

    private void getLargestFunc(int[] getLargest1, int[] getLargest2)
    {
        int largest = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < getLargest1.length; i++)
        {
            if (getLargest1[i] > largest)
            {
                largest = getLargest1[i];
                System.out.println("Largest: " + largest);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < getLargest2.length; i++)
        {
            if (getLargest2[i] > largest)
            {
                largest = getLargest2[i];
                System.out.println("Largest: " + largest);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move your `print` stmt outside the for loops.

Comment: Move each print statement after its for-loop, and also reset the `largest` variable to `0` after the first loop

Comment: @BackSlash or the first element of each array

Comment: call System.out.println("Largest" + largest) after the for loop. calling ti during will only print out the variable largest each time the if condition is true

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in this way too

```
  int[] getLargest1 = {3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 5, 23, 14};
  int[] getLargest2 = {33, 23, 41, 9, 17, 51, 23, 45};
  Arrays.sort(getLargest1);
  Arrays.sort(getLargest2);

 System.out.println("Largest values " + getLargest1[getLargest1.length-1]
                                    +" and "+getLargest2[getLargest2.length-1]);
```

Output:

```
 Largest values 23 and 51
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to move the

```
System.out.println("Largest: " + largest);
```

statements outside of the `for` loops. Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getLargest2.length; i++)
{
    if (getLargest2[i] > largest)
    {
        largest = getLargest2[i];
      }
}
System.out.println("Largest: " + largest);
```

Of course, the `largest` variable has to be reset after the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < getLargest1.length; i++)
{
   if (getLargest1[i] > largest)
   {
       largest = getLargest1[i];
   }
}

System.out.println("Largest: " + largest);
```

Your `print` statement should be out of the loop, or your just iterating through all the changes in largest. That's why it's giving you weird outputs.

---

I would just make one method that can be used for both arrays. This makes a more usable method.

```
public void start()
{
    int[] getLargest1 = {3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 5, 23, 14};
    int[] getLargest2 = {33, 23, 41, 9, 17, 51, 23, 45};
    System.out.println(getLargestFunc(getLargest1));
    System.out.println(getLargestFunc(getLargest2));
}

private int getLargestFunc(int[] array){
     if(array == null) return null;
     largest = array[0];
     for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
         if(array[i] > largest){
            largest = array[i];
         }
     }
    return largest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing at wrong place you should print outside your loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getLargest1.length; i++)
        {
            if (getLargest1[i] > largest)
            {
                largest = getLargest1[i];

            }
        }
        System.out.println("Largest: " + largest);

        largest = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < getLargest2.length; i++)
        {
            if (getLargest2[i] > largest)
            {
                largest = getLargest2[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Largest: " + largest);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to put the system println outside of loop operation..

Comment: `largest` also needs to be reset.

Answer (score 0):

One more way is - ArrayUtils (org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils) and Collections

```
    int[] getLargest1 = {3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 5, 23, 14};
    int[] getLargest2 = {33, 23, 41, 9, 17, 51, 23, 45};


    List a = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(getLargest1));
    System.out.println("Largest :"+Collections.max(a));

    List b = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(getLargest2));
    System.out.println("Largest :"+Collections.max(b));
```

Comment: It gives `[I@5483cd` without `ArrayUtils.toObject(arr)` instead of `23`

Answer (score 0):

Try (untested):

```
final int largest1 = IntStream.of(getLargest1).max().getAsInt();
final int largest2 = IntStream.of(getLargest2).max().getAsInt();

return largest1 >= largest2 ? largest1 : largest2;
```